# spec fill_in for text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, specifications

I have a form with this 
= text_field_tag "user_info[name]", nil, placeholder: "Your Name", required: ""
And I want to make the spec to fill in the form, I try with fill_in "[user_info][name]", :with => "Joe" but it give me the error Unable to find field "[user_info][name]" any idea? I already add the js:true and I inspect the element and have id="user_info_name" and name= "user_info[name]". This form is a partial render on another page, do I have to add something else?

Comment: You should edit this question and format it properly.  StackOverflow markup is not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have extraneous square brackets around `user_info` in your spec.

Try this:

```
fill_in "user_info[name]", :with => "Joe"
```

If that doesn't work, try referencing the field by its ID:

```
fill_in "user_info_name", :with => "Joe"
```